# Cannot gather gradients for GradientDescentOptimizer in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to gather the gradient steps for each step of the GradientDescentOptimizer within TensorFlow, however I keep running into a TypeError when I try to pass the result of `apply_gradients()` to `sess.run()`. The code I'm trying to run is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*log(y))

# note that up to this point, this example is identical to the tutorial on tensorflow.org

gradstep = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).compute_gradients(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
batch_x,batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
print sess.run(gradstep, feed_dict={x:batch_x,y_:batch_y})
```

Note that if I replace the last line with `print sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_x,y_:batch_y})`, where `train_step = tf.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)`, the error is not raised. My confusion arises from the fact that `minimize` calls `compute_gradients` with exactly the same arguments as its first step. Can someone explain why this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Optimizer.compute_gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.compute_gradients) method returns a list of (`Tensor`, `Variable`) pairs, where each tensor is the gradient with respect to the corresponding variable.

`Session.run()` expects a list of `Tensor` objects (or objects convertible to a `Tensor`) as its first argument. It does not understand how to handle a list of pairs, and hence you get a `TypeError` which you try to run `sess.run(gradstep, ...)`

The correct solution depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to fetch all of the gradient values, you can do the following:

```
grad_vals = sess.run([grad for grad, _ in gradstep], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

# Then, e.g., nuild a variable name-to-gradient dictionary.
var_to_grad = {}
for grad_val, (_, var) in zip(grad_vals, gradstep):
    var_to_grad[var.name] = grad_val
```

If you also want to fetch the variables, you can execute the following statement separately:

```
sess.run([var for _, var in gradstep])
```

...though note that—without further modification to your program—this will just return the initial values for each variable.
You will have to run the optimizer's training step (or otherwise call [`Optimizer.apply_gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.apply_gradients)) to update the variables.

Answer (score 1):

minimize calls compute_gradients followed by apply_gradients: it's possible you're missing the second step.

compute_gradients just returns the grads / variables, but doesn't apply the update rule to them.

Here is an example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f2bd0fc399606d14b55f3f7d732d013f32b33dd5/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L69

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not trying to minimize the optimizer, I'm just trying to print out the gradients at each step. The reason why I bring up the minimize counter example is that it involves calling compute_gradients, so one would expect that a call to that function with the same arguments would also produce an error.